# Error building BigQueryJavaGettingStarted java sample

Tags: google-bigquery

trying to compile BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java

from this location:

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/java/gettingstarted/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted/src/main/java/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java

Cant't seem fix the error:

Line:125, return Bigquery.builder(..... - method is undefined.

Using v2-rev88-1.15.0

Is the code old, or the Jars out of date? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Changing the code to the following seemed to fix the problem:  Bigquery bq = new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential); Example code looks out of date...

Comment: OK. I finally got the sample app working. I wanted to test the various OAuth2 flows and this sample app is a good way to do that. Just make the change mentioned in my previous comment, create the OAuth Json file  and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Closing question since I got this working. My main interest was in debugging Google's RESTFul API. I didn't realize that you could do this with Python BQ tool. There is a swi